# Apply Codemirror to multiple textarea by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

I'm aware that it's possible to apply codemirror to multiple textarea by Id, but unfortunately I need to use class because the textarea I'm using already have ids from other scripts.

Here's my code so far.

#### `HTML`

```
<textarea class="textarea-class"></textarea>
<textarea class="textarea-class"></textarea>
```

#### `JS`

```
$('.textarea-class').each(function(index, elem){
      CodeMirror.fromTextArea(elem, {
        lineWrapping: true,
        mode: "javascript",
        theme: "neat",
        lineNumbers: true,
      });
});
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/zavusegoto/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: You forgot to add jQuery in your jsbin example

Comment: Thanks. I feel so dumb haha.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't abel to pass a jQuery element! It has to be a regular element. To solve this problem we will loop through the Array of elements from the `document.querySelectorAll('.textarea-class')` and pass each into the `CodeMirror.fromTextarea()` function.

#### `JS`

```
var textareas = document.querySelectorAll(".textarea-class");

for (var i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++) {
    CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textareas[i], {
        lineWrapping: true,
        mode: "javascript",
        theme: "neat",
        lineNumbers: true
     });
}
```

Demo with CodeMirror libraries and stylesheets: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OvLxaG

Comment: This is the vanilla javascript version. The OP's version actually worked after including jQuery - `elem` is a DOM element, not a jQuery objectl See [each in the jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/each/).